# How to find overlaps between two different dataframes and write overlap into corresponding bins

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics, overlap, genomicranges

How to find overlaps between two different dataframes and then write this data into corresponding bins?

For example I would have a dataframe (represented by the first table here) that contains the start and end points of a subset of e.g. a sequence of numbers ranging from 0 to 10.000, but those subsets give no information about the rest of those 10.000 numbers/do not contain them.

| Chromosome | Start | End | Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ch1 | 151 | 250 | 100 |
| ch1 | 301 | 410 | 110 |
| ch1 | 461 | 500 | 40 |
| ch+n | n | n | n |

Another dataframe (represented by the second table) is consisting of small, 100 numbers-short intervalls spanning this whole sequence, from 0 to 10.000.

| Chromosome | bin | BinStart | BinEnd | Number of Overlaps |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ch1 | 1 | 1 | 100 |  |
| ch1 | 2 | 101 | 201 |  |
| ch1 | 3 | 301 | 400 |  |
| ch1 | 4 | 401 | 500 |  |
| ch+n | n | n | n |  |

The different dataframes therefore also have a different number of rows, and the first only spans parts of the 10.000 numbers, while the second spans all of it.

I thought of using a loop that goes through each the BinStart and BinEnd of each row, then looks if the intervall is between the one of the Start and End values of the first dataframe, then fill the Number of Overlaps column, but did not know how to accomplish that.

Perhaps I should divide my bins into bins spanning only 1 number, and check if this one number is between two values, then if yes = fill with the number 1, if no = with the number 0, and later merge my bins again into bins spanning 100 numbers?

The output/result at the end should look like this:

| Chromosome | bin | Start | End | Number of Overlaps |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ch1 | 1 | 1 | 100 | 0 |
| ch1 | 2 | 101 | 201 | 50 |
| ch1 | 3 | 301 | 400 | 100 |
| ch1 | 4 | 401 | 500 | 50 |
| ch+n | n | n | n | n |

Are maybe the mutate function of dplyr or the findOverlaps or the GenomicRanges package useful here?

Thank you all in advance, and have a nice weekend!

Comment: Is it right that you want your output to have 100 rows for each chromosome, one for each potential bin, along with the amount covered for each? Are there ever any overlapping segments or is that by definition impossible?

Comment: Shouldn't your output also have 50 overlap in the 201-300 bin?

Comment: @JonSpring yeah, apparently I did not add that row.

Comment: I want my output to give me a number for each potential bin, along with the amount covered, aye. There are no overlaps in my first table, no.